# Xamarin: Background Method

Tags: xamarin, timer, background

I have this chunk of code in xamarin.forms:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec), () =>
                    {
                        Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            await GetCurrentLocation();
                        });
                        return true;
                    });
```

This method will call the method called GetCurrentLocation() every sec seconds. It works just fine when the app is opened and when it is in background, BUT it doesn't work when the app is in background and the phone screen is locked. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/

Comment: Already read the documentation. Isn't there a Xamarin.Forms solution?

Comment: background jobs are highly platform dependent.  There are cross platform libraries like Shiny you can look into, but you should really be aware of the restrictions each platform has in place

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Android, you need to register a foreground service (like google maps does).
On iOS, you need to enable background modes in the info.plist and enable the background location tracking option.

Comment: Isn't out there a library (like Shiny) that can easily implements that? Like, I'm having a lot of issues trying to register foreground/background service with Android.

Comment: You can post a new question to show the problem you met. @TestRDT